# less @import with variable interpolation

Tags: angular, less

I've found plenty of issues discussing about this, but it seems to have been

> [fixed](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/2246) in version 1.4.0. I
>   also found [other
>   people](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/410#issuecomment-452804015)
>   saying it broke in version 3.9.0, which is mine. I've tried updating
>   it to latest (3.11.x), no effect.

The way explained in the docs doesn't seem to work

```
@import "@{themes}/tidal-wave.less";
```

The console outputs the following:

> client:159 ./src/styles.less
>   (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--16-3!./src/styles.less)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>
> @client-dir: "foo"; @import
>   "assets/less/@{client-dir}/_variables.less"; ^ Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded
>         in C:\localpath\src\styles.less (line 710, column 0)

Is there any fix or workaround? I've also tried using guards for conditional importing, but I had a problem with the variable scoping.

I'm trying to build themes, but the variables must be imported in styles.less because of [ng-zorro](https://ng.ant.design/).

EDIT: It seems to be a problem with angular. I've tried creating a vanilla project with less in codepen, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I don’t understand how this would work. Is the theme variable declared at build time?

Comment: @bryan60 I was thinking about using modifyVars() to change the client variable

Comment: or do something like [this](https://www.developer.com/java/setting-client-specific-styles-in-angular-using-less.js.html)

Comment: a few problems with that approach... 1. angular is expecting to precompile your less to css for production and dev builds.  You'd need to modify the build pipeline to not do this and to include less.js in your bundle. 2. while this is technically possible, it will be a big drag on performance, and is not recommended in a production environment 3. it's questionable of how this would possibly mix with encapsulated styles. it may not be possible.

Comment: that article is referencing doing this at build time, not on the fly, which you could do and would perform fine, but you'd need to modify the build pipeline still. and it's still questionable of how this would mix with encapsulated styles, which the article seems to gloss over a bit. developer.com doesn't have the feel of a very authoritative source tbh.  there's still a big WHY question, of why if you just want to import a bunch of different theme files, or tweak your import for builds, seems easier to just write 10 lines of imports or modify a static variabkle rather than rewrite the build

Comment: @bryan60 I agree that this solutions seems weird, but I can't think of other ways, as that was also part of my question. Is there a way that I can dynamically import my less files? or what did you mean by "write 10 lines of imports"? and which static variable could that be?

Comment: all of your less is transpiled to css before deployment, css doesn't have a concept of imports or variables at this point in time.  thus You don't truly have access to dynamic variables or imports once built and deployed.  Variables in less exist to make your life easier when you want to change things down the line, not so you can create dynamic styles on the fly in your application.  You could just import all of your theme files to some themes.less file, and wrap them in theme selectors and apply them conditionally that way.  I'd read up on css themeing strategies if that's your goal